# how to find overlapping region between images in opencv?

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to implement alpha blending with two images for image stitching .
My first image is this ->
[image]

here is my second image ->
[image]

here is my result image ->
[image]

As you can see the result is not proper.I think I first have to find  the overlapping region between then and then implement alpha blending on the overlapping part.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, have you seen a new "stitching" module introduced in OpenCV 2.3?

It provides a set of building blocks for stitching pipeline including blending and "finding an overlap" (e.g. registration) steps. Here is a documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/stitching.html and an example of stitching application: [stitching_detailed.cpp](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp?rev=6906)

I recommend you to study the code of this sample for better understanding of the details.

Regarding the finding of overlap there are several common approaches in computer vision:

- optical flow
- template matching
- feature matching

For your case I recommend the last one - it works very well on the photos. And this approach is already implemented in OpenCV - explore the OpenCv source and see how the `cv::detail::BestOf2NearestMatcher` works.

Comment: "Image registration" is another term from the computer vision world that might be useful; it refers to the process of aligning multiple overlapping images.

Comment: I really, really wonder how you would use Optical Flow here?! Optical Flow is supposed to work on a sequence of images...

Answer (score 1):

I think the most common approach is SIFT, find a few keypoints in both images, then warp them to get your result. See [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/feature_detection.html)

[Here](http://tobw.net/index.php?cat_id=2&project=Panorama%20Stitching%20Demo%20in%20Matlab) are explanations about SIFT and panorama stitching.