# Feature detection in OpenCV to merge two images

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection

Is it somehow possible to merge two images captured by searching for identical features in OpenCV in both images?
My images will always contain sheets of papers which are too big to be captured in one single frame thus I need to take two or more frames - the images are captured so that there is some overlapping area, see:

Top picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7p9o.jpg

Bottom picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1guw.jpg

IDEA: Restrict features to only move up/down and not to the right etc.. Even more so, the length of all vectors between two identical features in both images has to be more or less identical, as the area is overlapping. OpenCV also only has to look at the very bottom of picture one and at the very top of picture two for overlapping features. All the other areas are NOT of interest...

Edit: Okay I found some sources about this finally with some good links in the answers: [how to find overlapping region between images in opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855825/how-to-find-overlapping-region-between-images-in-opencv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the linked question you have posted is the way to go. Local features might not work very well for your case (sheet of paper), if it doesn't maybe you should do a kind of row scanner where you compare a few rows from one image to rows of the other image until the row comparison has a similarity above some threshold. Basically finding where the images should intersect.

For Java image stitching you might check this OpenCV alternative: [BoofCV](http://boofcv.org)

Or this dedicated stitching library: [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/)

At worst case you can check how they do the stitching and code yourself a simpler version.

Comment: Problem is, that there is no binding for java for the stitching API of OpenCV :( And I definitely need it in Java :( Rowscanning is a good idea too, but quite difficult I suppose as I'd need to have certain thresholds to cover the insurance (probabilitic models) because the second image is certainly captured a bit different /rotated, skewed, different illumination etc)..

Comment: Yeah that is true, I have placed some alternatives in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Didnt know about BoofCV, does also look nice, so Ill keep that in mind. Hugin also looks pretty well - I need to check out if it runs under Android as well... :) Edit: Ah I thought Hugin was a library but actually it's a full running program which I probably can access via API, but not on Android then :(