# How can I find an overlapping parts of two grayscale images in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am providing the link that shows images that I am talking about.

Here is the link shows these images. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX9fo.jpg

I have two grayscale images. First and Second images in the list.

They are intersecting eachother like that. Third image in the list

I need to find the overlapping area. Then extract these areas from both images to create 2 separate equal size images. Fourth and Fifth images in the list.

How can I do this using OpenCV with C++ API? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855825/how-to-find-overlapping-region-between-images-in-opencv

Comment: DO you mean a creation of panoramic images ? If so, check this explanation : http://www1.inf.tu-dresden.de/~ds24/lehre/cv1_ws_2013/cv1ex3_ws_2013.pdf

Comment: Actually, I want to register two images from different modalities. I need to calculate their joint entropy. To do that, I need to extract intersections of them.

Comment: so you have 2 parts: 1. register: try SIFT/SURF or something like that. 2. etract overlapping/intersecting area. that's easy: compute a binary mask for both image and warp/transform/register them with the same transformation as the original images. then check all pixels in panorama and select only the regions where both masks are set.

Comment: First, I need to extract areas then I will register them. Why I need to extract first is I will calculate their mutual information. My registration algorithm is not feature based, it is area based. Let's forget about registration part for now. How can I extract these overlapping areas using mask?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to cut them up into evenly sized rectangles and do a template match with regions of interest from one image into the other. The location of the template matching can then tell you something about the overlap. So if a similar rectangle from the middle of picture A is found on the bottom left of picture B you can probably estimate the overlap. If you do this for many regions of interest you can get a pretty good estimate.

Another option might be to try to match points between the two images with something like SIFT

Comment: This problem is similar to [image-stitching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching), so it could be solved using algorithms that were designed for that purpose.